# python sax parsing problem,，code not work

Tags: python, xml

I want to get the value under the node, if not, fill in the null value, but, it doesn't look like it's working properly, I'm not sure what's wrong

```
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
import xml.sax

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"><dimension ref="A1"/><sheetViews><sheetView workbookViewId="0"/></sheetViews><sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15.0"/><cols><col min="1" max="1" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="2" max="2" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="3" max="3" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="4" max="4" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="5" max="5" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="6" max="6" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="7" max="7" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="8" max="8" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="9" max="9" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="10" max="10" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="11" max="11" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="12" max="12" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="13" max="13" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="14" max="14" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="15" max="15" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="16" max="16" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="17" max="17" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="18" max="18" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/><col min="19" max="19" width="12.8515625" customWidth="true"/></cols><sheetData>
<row r="1" customHeight="true" ht="35.25" s="9" customFormat="1">
<c r="A1" s="10" t="inlineStr"><is><t>按约上门明细报表</t></is></c><c r="B1" s="10"></c><c r="C1" s="10"></c><c r="D1" s="10"></c><c r="E1" s="10"></c><c r="F1" s="10"></c><c r="G1" s="10"></c><c r="H1" s="10"></c><c r="I1" s="10"></c><c r="J1" s="10"></c><c r="K1" s="10"></c><c r="L1" s="10"></c><c r="M1" s="10"></c><c r="N1" s="10"></c><c r="O1" s="10"></c><c r="P1" s="10"></c><c r="Q1" s="10"></c><c r="R1" s="10"></c><c r="S1" s="10"></c></row>
<row r="2" customHeight="true" ht="22.5" s="9" customFormat="1">
<c r="A2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>工贸</t></is></c><c r="B2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>产业</t></is></c><c r="C2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>服务商编码</t></is></c><c r="D2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>服务商</t></is></c><c r="E2" s="12" t="inlineStr"><is><t>服务兵工号</t></is></c><c r="F2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>服务兵</t></is></c><c r="G2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>工单号</t></is></c><c r="H2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>登记时间</t></is></c><c r="I2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>要求服务时间</t></is></c><c r="J2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>服务商结单时间</t></is></c><c r="K2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>实际服务类型名称</t></is></c><c r="L2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>实际服务名称</t></is></c><c r="M2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>结单方式</t></is></c><c r="N2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>首次签到前的最后一次预约时间</t></is></c><c r="O2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>首次签到时间</t></is></c><c r="P2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>签到地址</t></is></c><c r="Q2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>首次签到距离</t></is></c><c r="R2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>网点到用户家距离</t></is></c><c r="S2" s="11" t="inlineStr"><is><t>是否按约</t></is></c></row>
</sheetData>
<mergeCells><mergeCell ref="A1:S1"/>
</mergeCells><pageMargins bottom="0.75" footer="0.3" header="0.3" left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75"/><drawing r:id="rId1"/></worksheet>
"""


class SessionTokenHeadler(ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        # ContentHandler.__init__(self)
        self.inside_text_tag=False
        self.data=[]
        self.info = []
        self.flag=0
        self.temp=0
    def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
        if tag=="c":
            if attributes.getLength()!=2:
                # print(attributes.getLength())
                self.inside_text_tag=True
                self.flag+=1
            else:
                self.info.append("")
    def endElement(self, tag):
        # print(tag)
        if tag=="row":
            # print(tag)
            self.data.append(self.info)
            self.inside_text_tag=False
            self.info.clear()
    def characters(self, content):
        if self.inside_text_tag:
            self.temp+=1
            self.info.append(content)
    def get_info(self):
        return self.data,self.flag,self.temp


def get_xml_info(xmlString):
    Handler = SessionTokenHeadler()
    xml.sax.parseString(xmlString, Handler)
    # print(Handler.get_info())
    return Handler.get_info()
get_xml_info(data)
# len(get_xml_info(data))
```

My environment is PYTHON3.8, can you help me?
The return value of the current code is null. Why is it that I appended it, but it doesn't seem to work
([[], []], 20, 20)

Comment: ok,i know it,there should not use clear(),list.clear() will clear all data

Comment: Can you provide some details about how "code not work"? Including error messages would be helpful.